# Fusion table SQL query fails with numbers

Tags: sql, google-fusion-tables

I'm making a tiny webapp to see what are the pub's specials around you and I have a very silly problem with my SQL query to fusion table.

Here is [my table](https://www.google.com/fusiontables/DataSource?docid=1BHnaan3YfSDq9_LzjthDXjj5dzJZANjLSb8JHPl5) and her is my query:

```
ST_INTERSECTS(address, CIRCLE(LATLNG(-33.898672999999995, 151.2063809), 300))
AND type IN ('food','drinks')
AND days CONTAINS 'tuesday'
AND from <= 2000
AND to >= 2000
```

My problem is with the `from` and `to`, if I remove them my query is fine and if I simplify them (remove `from` and put just `to > 0`) my query is still wrong.
As you can see in my fusion table, `from` and `to` are both numbers so I really don't get what's wrong.

**EDIT:**

So I'm using https://developers.google.com/apis-explorer/#p/fusiontables/v2/fusiontables.query.sql to test my queries:

[Good query](https://developers.google.com/apis-explorer/#p/fusiontables/v2/fusiontables.query.sql?sql=SELECT%20*%20FROM%201BHnaan3YfSDq9_LzjthDXjj5dzJZANjLSb8JHPl5%20WHERE%20%20%20%20%20ST_INTERSECTS(address%252C%20CIRCLE(LATLNG(-33.898672999999995%252C%20151.2063809)%252C%20300))%20%20%20%20%20AND%20type%20IN%20('food'%252C'drinks')%20%20%20%20%20AND%20days%20CONTAINS%20'tuesday'&_h=11&) (200 OK):

```
SELECT *
FROM 1BHnaan3YfSDq9_LzjthDXjj5dzJZANjLSb8JHPl5
WHERE
    ST_INTERSECTS(address, CIRCLE(LATLNG(-33.898672999999995, 151.2063809), 300))
    AND type IN ('food','drinks')
    AND days CONTAINS 'tuesday'
```

[Bad query](https://developers.google.com/apis-explorer/#p/fusiontables/v2/fusiontables.query.sql?sql=SELECT%20*%20FROM%201BHnaan3YfSDq9_LzjthDXjj5dzJZANjLSb8JHPl5%20WHERE%20%20%20%20%20ST_INTERSECTS(address%252C%20CIRCLE(LATLNG(-33.898672999999995%252C%20151.2063809)%252C%20300))%20%20%20%20%20AND%20type%20IN%20('food'%252C'drinks')%20%20%20%20%20AND%20days%20CONTAINS%20'tuesday'%20%20%20%20%20AND%20from%20%253C%253D%201619%20%20%20%20%20AND%20to%20%253E%253D%201619&_h=12&*):

```
SELECT *
FROM 1BHnaan3YfSDq9_LzjthDXjj5dzJZANjLSb8JHPl5
WHERE
    ST_INTERSECTS(address, CIRCLE(LATLNG(-33.898672999999995, 151.2063809), 300))
    AND type IN ('food','drinks')
    AND days CONTAINS 'tuesday'
    AND from <= 1619
    AND to >= 1619
```

I get this error but I don't see what's wrong because `<=` is in the docs:

```
{
 "error": {
  "errors": [
   {
    "domain": "fusiontables",
    "reason": "badQueryCouldNotParse",
    "message": "Invalid query: Parse error near 'from' (line 1, position 218).",
    "locationType": "parameter",
    "location": "q"
   }
  ],
  "code": 400,
  "message": "Invalid query: Parse error near 'from' (line 1, position 218)."
 }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`from` & `to` are reserved words in fusion table, here is [the list of reserved words](https://developers.google.com/fusiontables/docs/v1/using?hl=de#reserved):

```
AND
ASC
AS
BY
CASE
CIRCLE
CONTAINS
CONTAIN
CREATE
DELETE
DESCRIBE
DESC
DOES
DROP
ENDS
EQUAL
FROM
GROUP
IGNORING
IN
INSERT
INTO
LATLNG
LIKE
LIMIT
MATCHES
NEAR
NOT
OFFSET
ORDER
POLYGON
RECTANGLE
ROWID
SELECT
SET
SHOW
SKIP
ST_DISTANCE
ST_INTERSECTS
STARTS
TABLES
TABLE
TO
UPDATE
VALUES
VIEW
WHERE
WITH
ID
NUMBER
DOCID
STRING
```

I figured it out because they were blue in the syntax highlighting in my question.

Answer (score 0):

If you try that query from the Fusion Tables UI, you also see no results, because no values match those criteria. The days are "monday" and "tuesday", and the times are 1130-1400 and 1800-2359.

Comment: Sorry I should I've put a correct query (I've edited my first post). The problem is not that it's not returning anything put that the query fails and returns all the thing.